# My python lambda function does not return the lambda function name

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda

I have tried invoking a `lambda` function in AWS. I have got it triggered with an `S3` event and below is my code. I could get the bucket and key from the event records. I was trying to get the `lambda function name` as part of the invocation and was unable to do it. Could i get the function name from the event.

```
def getEnv(event):
   key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8')
   bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
   lambdaName = event['lambdaName'][0]

   environment = {'env': bucke, 'lambdaName': lambdaName}
```

Comment: lambda functions generally don't have a name (although you can set one (->`__name__`), if you want to; this is python); this is because they are an expression rather than a statement. (`3+2` is an expression, `a=b` is a statement.)
This results in the property, that the lambda function cannot now it's name (`a=lambda x: x*2` -> `lambda x: x*2` is evaluated first, and then it is assigned to `a`), or (if properly used, this should be the only option) don't have one anyway (`cubes = map(lambda x: x**3, li)`).

Comment: @CodingLambdas: this isn't about the *Python* lambda syntax, but about the [AWS Lambda service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, ok. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get this from the Context object, not the Event. Use `context.function_name`. More documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me.